# Show one todo tree with two different states

Tags: org-mode

Hi I would like to make this function show a tree with headings in `NEXT` and `WAITING` status.

```el
    (defun show-NEXT-in-subtree ()
       "Narrow to a subtree and show only headings with NEXT and WAITING keywords"
       (interactive)
       (org-narrow-to-subtree)
       (org-show-todo-tree '(3 4)) ;; NEXT|WAITING
       (org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c))
```

I don't understand how to do it in the correct way according to help.

> With a prefix argument (or by using C-c / T), search for a specific TODO. You will be prompted for the keyword, and you can also give a list of keywords like KWD1|KWD2|... to list entries that match any one of these keywords. With a numeric prefix argument N, show the tree for the Nth keyword in the option org-todo-keywords.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Try `(org-show-todo-tree "NEXT|WAITING")` ?

Comment: @NickD this results in the tree only showing the first keyword `(aka org-show-todo-tree 1)` I tried to pass the universal argument `(org-show-todo-tree '(4))` but then emacs propmts me to enter the keywords instead of accepting predefined ones.

Comment: See my answer: `org-show-todo-tree` is pretty useless in a lisp program - it is meant to be used interactively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org-show-todo-tree` is incorrigibly interactive, so we go under the covers and see that it uses `org-occur` to find what it wants. That allows us to bypass it altogether and write your function like this:

```el
 (defun show-NEXT-in-subtree ()
       "Narrow to a subtree and show only headings with NEXT and WAITING keywords"
       (interactive)
       (org-narrow-to-subtree)
       (org-occur (concat "^" org-outline-regexp " *" "\\(NEXT\\|WAITING\\)"))
       (org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c))
```

That constructs the regexp that we give to `org-occur` explicitly: beginning of line, stars, spaces and then either `NEXT` or `WAITING`. There are easier ways to do the regexp perhaps, but these are new tricks and I am an old dog.

Comment: I use same same behavior in my org workflow. if you add `(outline-up-heading 4)` inside of the function also you will not need to put cursor to the exact point. Disadvantage it gives more visibility :)